# Can I use ifelse for an "eat least one" condition to apply to get my output

Tags: r, if-statement

I am very very new to R. Trying to create an ifelse command that will give me an output not only by OR but can also add up the conditions stated (i.e I am trying to find an "AND/OR" command):

Thanks so much!

```
CAT_PREDICTOR_TABLE$ANY <- ifelse(CAT_PREDICTOR_TABLE$a == "1" | 
                                  CAT_PREDICTOR_TABLE$b == "1" | 
                                  CAT_PREDICTOR_TABLE$c >0 | 
                                  CAT_PREDICTOR_TABLE$d >0,
                                  1,
                                  0)
```

With the above command it is only giving a result of 1 if only a single condition applies. I would like the variable to result as 1 if AT LEAST ONE of these conditions apply.

Comment: you can also use `case_when`

Comment: _I would like the variable to result as 1 if AT LEAST ONE of these conditions apply_ -> your code should do this? I'm not sure what isn't working for you. And are you sure CAT_PREDICTOR_TABLE$a has a `string` class? Because you are comparing it to the string "1"

Comment: Welcome to SO, Nurit Katz! This is a good start to your first question. It can be improved slightly by including sample data. The "best" (preferred, unambiguous) method is to paste the output from `dput(.)` with your data, with _just enough_ data to get the point across (but not all hundreds of rows), for instance the output from `dput(CAT_PREDICTOR_TABLE[1:10, 1:5])` to provide 10 rows of 5 columns (`dput(head(x))` also works if all columns are relevant). When you're ready with this, [edit] your question and paste this into a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Thank you!

Comment: You're looking for base R's `any()` as in if _any_ of these are true.